# GraphQL vs Normalized Data Structure Advantages

Tags: graphql

From [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape#designing-a-normalized-state):

> This [normalized] state structure is much flatter overall. Compared to
> the original nested format, **this is an improvement** in several ways...

From https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr
:

> Many APIs, public or not, return JSON data that has deeply nested objects. **Using data in this kind of structure is often very difficult** for JavaScript applications, especially those using Flux or Redux.

Seems like normalized database-ish data structures are better to work with on front end. Then why GraphQL is so popular if it's whole language style is revolved around quickly getting any **nested** data? Why do people use it then?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of discussion is off-topic on SO ...

**it's not only about [normalized] structures** ...

`graphql` client (like apollo) takes care of all data fetching related nuances (error handling, cache, refetching, data conversion, and many more) also but hardly doable with redux.

**Different use cases, you can use both**:

- keep (complex) app state in redux,
- handle data fetching in apollo (you can use it for local state, too).

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at why we want to normalize the cache and what kind of work we have to do to get a normalized cache.

For the main page we fetch a list of TODOs and a list of high priority TODOS. Our two endpoints return the following data:

```json
{
  all: [{ id: 1, title: "TODO 1" }, { id: 2, title: "TODO 2" }, { id: 2, title: "TODO 2"}],
  highPrio: [{ id: 1, title: "TODO 1" }]
}
```

If we would store the data like this into our cache, we have a difficult time updating a single todo, because we have to update the todo in every array we have in our store or might have in our store in the future.

We can normalize the data and only store references in the array. This way we can easily update a single todo in a single place:

```json
{
  queries: {
    all: [{ ref: "Todo:1" }, { ref: "Todo:2" }, { ref: "Todo:2" }],
    highPrio: [{ ref: "Todo:1" }}]
  },
  refs: {
    "Todo:1": { id: 1, title: "TODO 1" },
    "Todo:2": { id: 2, title: "TODO 2" },
    "Todo:3": { id: 3, title: "TODO 3" }
  }
}
```

The downside is, that this shape of data is now much harder to use in our list component. We will have to transform the cache a lot, roughtly like so:

```
function denormalise(cache) {
  return {
    all: cache.queries.all.map(({ ref }) => cache.ref[ref]),
    highPrio: cache.queries.highPrio.map(({ ref }) => cache.ref[ref]),
  };
}
```

Notice how now updating `Todo:1` inside of the cache will update all queries that reference the todo automatically, if we run this function inside of the React component (this is often called a selector in Redux).

The magical thing about GraphQL is that it is a strict specification with a type system. This allows GraphQL clients like Apollo to globally identify objects and normalise that cache. At the same time it can also automatically denormalise the cache for you and update objects in the cache automatically after a mutation. This means that most of the time you have to write no caching logic at all. And this should explain why it is so popular: The best code is no code!

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(gql`
  { all { id title } highPrio { id title }
`);
```

This code automatically fetches the query on load, normalizes the response and writes it into the cache. Then denormalizes the cache back into the shape of the query using the cache data. Updates to elements in the cache automatically update all subscribed components.